# Looking for animated sci-fi movie from my childhood

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

I'm looking for an animated movie from my childhood. Actually it was only a few scenes at the end of a bootleg VHS tape (almost all tapes were bootleg in my country at that time).

1. The giant spaceship flies over the "camera" into the screen (the way intro text in Star Wars does, but from the top, not from the bottom)
2. Storyteller says something like "… we (or humanity) went into the depth of Space and found there nothing" (that's a translated voiceover as I recall it, not the exact text)
3. Next scene: an old (or just ugly) man with something that I remember as shepherd's crook, laughing.
4. (Possibly, don't recall exactly): Close up. This man's mouth, still laughing, planets in the background.

That's all, no more details. No logo, no title, I can't even tell if it was Japanese, or American or of any other origin. It was definitely not Russian.

It was made most possibly before 1990, and definitely before 1995. No CGI or render of any sort.

Comment: There';s not a lot to go on here. Can you describe the spaceship? Can you remember who the protagonists were? Can you describe the old man any better (ethnicity, accent)?

Comment: There were only few scenes, and then the tape ended, so that's all I have. I saw the spaceship only from the bottom as I've described. It was long, somewhere between blue and green, mostly flat, with pretty complex surface, but no significantly bulging superstructures. Not sure about propelling nozzles location — seems like sporadic. The man was drawn in a grotesque manner: large eyes, giant mouth, drops of saliva as he laughs. Can't tell anything about accent, as the recording had Russian voiceover.

Comment: And again, that's more than 15 years old memories. I can't guarantee anything to be exact (like, for instance, speceship colour may be actually gray, but I just remember is as dull bluish-greenish)

Comment: This is a very loose match (hence comment rather than answer) but could this be it "Ulysses 31" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ev1aBt-_Zs4

Comment: No, that's not "Ulysses 31". But thanks for the reference! I've never heard of this series before!

Comment: Edlothiad, happy? Quality improvement by deletion. @MaxKitsch check for "Captain Harlock". I bet that it's the right answer. I'm just not allowed to post it without being harassed.

Comment: @Haunt_House, thank you, but no, it's not "Captain Harlock". The ships in "Harlock", especially Arcadia have quite a distinct silhouette, the one I recall is one giant mess of superstructures without any resemplance to the sea ships.

Comment: @MaxKitsch Sorry, I hoped that it might be it. The quote was a pretty good match.

Comment: When you say "bootleg VHS", do you mean: the tape was in that state when it was bought, or one of your relative recorded stuffs on it using a VHS player?

Comment: @Clockwork, it was bought that way. Just to be clear: at that point there was little to no legal VHS market in Belarus, so you just couldn't buy non-bootleg VHS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found it. It's "Space Adventure Cobra" (1983).

[image: Spaceship]

[image: Man with shepherd's crook]

[image: Mouth, laughing]

Comment: Nice find. Have you really been looking for 6 years and now found it?

Comment: Don't forget to self-accept by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: @KerrAvon, I'd say I've finally asked the right question in the right time and place.